# Как получить элементы конкретного столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть следующий DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                 'B':[6,5,5,4,2,1]})
```

Kак я могу обратиться к примеру к 1,2,3 из списка значений ключа A, а затем записать их в какой-то список, чтобы использовать в дальнейшем?

И если я попробую обратиться к `df[0]`, я получу все значения по ключу А, как мне переписать значения в другой тип данных, в список например?

Comment: вопрос 1: - в список можно записать `[1,2,3]`. в текущей формулировке очень понятно что у вас на входе, но совершенно непонятно что вы хотите получить в результате...

Comment: хочу получить список или же кортеж, абсолютно не важно, важно только то, что мне надо вытащить конкретные данные из датафрейма. К примеру, на выходе нужен список C = [1,2,3]

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример результата, который вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [19]: res = df.query("A in [1,2,3]")

In [20]: res
Out[20]:
   A  B
0  1  6
1  2  5
2  3  5

In [21]: res["A"].to_list()
Out[21]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Приведу ещё один "традиционный" метод обращения к элементам столбца, если нужно, например, взять три первых значения столбца 'A':

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                 'B':[6,5,5,4,2,1]})

a = df['A'].values[:3]
print(a)
```

Вывод:

```
[1 2 3]
```

Это будет `numpy.ndarray`, к нему в принципе обращаться удобно, но если нужен именно `list`, то можно либо взять `list(a)`, либо воспользоваться `a.tolist()` примерно как в ответе MaxU.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_list'`. ;)  У объектов numpy есть метод `.tolist()` (без подчеркивания)